# Est-ce que la construction « à + -ant » a un sens ?

Tags: traduction, sens, constructions, participe-présent

Je traduis un document et je voudrais m'assurer que je comprends bien la clause :

> Dans l'hypothèse ou un [objet], après le transfert de propriété, serait constaté endommagé ou détruit par accident ou tout autre phénomène, X renoncerait à toute réclamation à imposant au fabricant l'élaboration à nouveau des [objets] détruits.

*= If an [object] is damaged or destroyed, X will waive any complaint by obliging (???)  the manufacturer to produce the destroyed [objects] once again.*

Est-ce que je comprends bien la construction *à imposant*?

Comment: This sentence is not particularly well written, *à imposant* is probably a typo for *en imposant*, the whole thing might come from an automatic translation tool.

Comment: Je crois que c'est un document français original. J'ai ajouté encore un peu plus de contexte, mais je ne pense pas que cela puisse aider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Warning: I’m not a native English speaker, nor am I a professional translator. I’m pretty sure your French is better than my English, so don’t take my proposed translations at face value.*

That French sentence is indeed quite poorly written. In particular, the “à imposant” doesn’t mean anything. Moreover, if one understands it as “imposant” or as “en imposant”, the meanings are completely different.

> [...]renoncerait à toute réclamation **imposant** au fabricant [...]

*[...]would waive any complaint which would oblige the manufacturer[...]*

Basically, if it breaks, that is your problem, not the manufacturer's. You waive the rights to complain by agreeing to the contract / buying the product.

> [...]renoncerait à toute réclamation **en imposant** au fabricant l’élaboration [...]

*[...]would waive any complaint by requiring from the manufacturer [...]*

If it breaks and you require replacement, you waive some rights of complaint. You waive these rights by reclaiming another product, *not* by agreeing to the terms in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. That's exacly what confuses me. Maybe someone will have an idea what the author had in mind with this “à imposant”.

Comment: @ghul The sentence simply isn't French. It's an editing mistake. The author most likely intended to write “… à toute réclamation imposant …” but especially in a legal document the signatories should go about amending the text.

Comment: If anyone is curious, it was probably supposed to be "à toute réclamation imposant". One "à" too many.

Answer (score -1):

*À imposant* is simply not correct French.
*En imposant* means “by forcing”, 
*imposant* means “which force”.